# When are Referral Badges (Promoter, Campaigner, and Activist) Awarded? Do they Require Referred Committers to Follow Through on their Commitments?

Tags: support, area-51, badges, referrals

I personally suspect that the referral badges (i.e. [`Promoter`](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/207/promoter), [`Campaigner`](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/208/campaigner), and [`Activist`](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/209/activist)) are only awarded when a proposal leaves the "Commitment" phase and enters the "Beta" phase, but I can't find any explicit confirmation for this.

The reason behind that impression is that I was lucky enough to refer, at the time of writing, 60+ committers to [the Vim proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14187/vi-vim-and-vixens) (*don't worry, this is not a referral link*), a number by which, according to the badges' definitions, I should be awarded the [`Promoter`](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/207/promoter) and [`Campaigner`](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/208/campaigner) badges. The proposal itself is currently in the "Commitment" phase, and I wasn't awarded any referral badge yet.

---

**Update:** I have just logged in to Area 51 to discover that I have been awarded the badges as expected. Since the proposal is still in the "Commitment" phase, **this clearly invalidates the above impression. But the question could still do with an answer**: I was originally under the impression that badges in general were awarded [almost] immediately, but AFAICT, I was awarded the [`Promoter`](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/207/promoter) badge around 38 hours after my 5th referred committer and the [`Campaigner`](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/208/campaigner) badge around 33 hours after my 25th one (*I've too much time on my hands, don't I?*).

---

Furthermore, Atwood's comment on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56580/could-there-be-a-way-to-award-those-that-successfully-promote-beta-se-sites/56581#56581) seems to suggest that awarding referral badges may depend on whether those who "commit" actually follow through on their commitments.

So, **when exactly are referral badges awarded, and do they require referred committers to follow through on their commitments?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Promoter, Campaigner, and Activist badges are all awarded hourly, just like the other badges. They don't depend on proposal phase or committer follow-though.

Our badge-granting task was unexpectedly down over the weekend though, so you received your Promoter and Campaigner badges about a day and half later than you should have.